# Sequelize - Querying string field with array of strings as input

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have records created in the below manner:

`{id: 1, units: 'unit 1,unit 2,unit 3' }
{id: 2, units: 'unit 2,unit 3' }
{id: 3, units: 'unit 2' }`

I need to get the records with respect to units.

`req.query.unit_name = 'unit 1,unit 2';`
`or`
`req.query.unit_name = 'unit 2,unit 1';`

`req.query.unit_name = req.query.unit_name.split(',');`

model: unitModel.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const unitModel = sequelize.define(
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        units: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    );
    return unitModel;
}
```

sequelize query:

```
db.unitModel.findAll({
    where: {
        units: {
            [Op.in]: req.query.unit_name
        }
    }
})
```

Can anyone help me how to get the records for string field using array of strings as input???

Comment: What is the error you are getting, kindly post that.

Comment: I am not getting any error but i need the proper query which i have to do to fetch records.

Comment: This is the proper way to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can split `req.query.unit_name` into array on `,`.

```
const unitName = req.query.unit_name.split(',');
db.unitModel.findAll({
where: {
    units: {
        [Op.in]: unitName
    }
}
});
```

Hope this helps!